# How to prevent two actions at a time in android

Tags: android

I have a textview and a listview in my page,If we click an item in listview or textview it will take us to diffrent different views.My problem is am able to click both textview and listview item at a time,How to block this?

Answer (score 0):

Set `onClickListener()` on `TextView`in `BaseAdapter`Class while you are inflating layout to

ListView.And ListView is by default clickable.Now if you click TextView it will perform

different action and on rest part of row different action will perform.

Comment: Now textview and listview item will perform different actions and textview is not part of listview .My problem is am able to click both at atime.